# How do I form and pour long concrete steps for an exterior staircase?

Tags: concrete, stairs

I want to replace some concrete blocks with proper stairs in front of my house. They are wobbly and dangerous. Attached is a photo of what is currently there.

I have been unable to find anything about building a form of this size for stairs. I found lots of stairs tutorials, but they are all using actual stair forms.

Anybody have a good tutorial with visuals for doing this properly?!

There will be a total of 4 steps, roughly 5ft x 3ft each.

[image: Current steps]

Comment: It's not so much the concrete, it's the landscaping and support structure.  You're going to need a really solid base or everything will tilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct shuttering (usually timber) to hold the concrete in position while it cures. You'd usually have the shutter that forms the face of the stair "open" to allow concrete under to the lower step.

( [This shows the principal](http://www.fao.org/docrep/s1250e/S1250E7J.GIF) )

If you use a stiff mix of concrete, it won't flow under the shutter forming the face of the stairs, but you will have to work harder to compact it to get a good finish. If you do find the occasional air void when you remove the shutter, you can fill in with a cement mix.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info John! I will have to do some more planning on this for sure.